# Parsing Error Response from Oracle CLOB having a JSON Call

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, clob

I have a following code that generates the response payload from APEX call.  When the webservice is successful, the response comes out just fine. No issues.

However, when response has errors, I am unable to display the error with its full description using PLSQL API.

However, if I use the same payload and run it through POSTMAN or SOAPUI, I get full error.

**How can I parse and receive complete error description from PLSQL?**

Here is the code snippet in question:

```
 l_resp := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url => g_fusion_url,
         p_credential_static_id => l_crd,
         p_http_method => l_method, p_body => p_body);
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STATUSCODE:'||apex_web_service.g_status_code);
        IF apex_web_service.g_status_code >= 400 THEN
            apex_debug.info('Request Body is %s', sys.dbms_lob.substr(l_resp, 4000, 1));

            raise_application_error(-20001, 'API Error2: '
                                            || apex_web_service.g_status_code
                                            || '-'
                                            || sys.dbms_lob.substr(l_resp, 1, 531));--1.4
```

**If I run the Payload through SOAP UI, you will see that, we get complete description**

[image]

**But the same API from SQL Developer or SQL Plus gives only following, which is not enough.**

```
Error report -
ORA-20001: Error in Main:[Brkpoint:M01|-20004|ORA-20004: Error in apinvoices:ORA-20004: Error in Request_fusion:ORA-20001: API Error2: 400-
ORA-06512: at "PROCORE_WH_DATA.XXMOR_RR_BILLING_INVOICE_PROC", line 689
ORA-06512: at line 1]
ORA-06512: at "PROCORE_WH_DATA.XXMOR_RR_BILLING_INVOICE_PROC", line 52
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

Please advise how can I resolve this.  My ask is, I want to capture full length error message like it shows in the SOAP UI in PLSQ Calls.

Thank you
Darsh

Comment: And... what is the response you are getting in pl/sql ? The one that you're unable to parse ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct Sir.  I am only getting the http error code 400 when using PLSQL

Comment: well in that case the rest endpoint doesn't offer you more information.... nothing you can do about that. The rest developer might choose to give more information in a json response but in this case it looks like he hasn't. 
In my opinion... I don't think it's appropriate to show a database error as a rest response.

Comment: Actually, REST end point does give sufficient information for error responses. We can see pretty clear error description when we make the same call using SoapUI or Postman.   It is only on PSLQL Side where I only get error code and nothing else. And that is my problem.   As you can see from the screens above,  I am getting REST response and trying to parse first 500 characters, but still it does not work.  Only 400 error code keeps showing up

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be different position (switched places) of parameters 2 & 3 in SubStr() vs dbms_lob.SubStr() functions.
**SubStr**(char, position, length)
**dbms_lob.SubStr**(clob, amount, offset)

Your code dbms_lob.substr(l_resp, 1, 531) results with 1 char at position 531
what you need probably is ***SubStr(l_resp, 1, 531)*** since you already got 4000 chars l_resp string.

See the code below:

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Declare
    my_text_varchar     VarChar2(10) := '0123456789';
    my_text_clob        CLOB := '0123456789';
Begin
    dbms_output.put_line('SubStr(my_text_varchar, 1, 10)        --->' || SubStr(my_text_varchar, 1, 10));
    dbms_output.put_line('dbms_lob.SubStr(my_text_clob, 1, 10): --->' || dbms_lob.SubStr(my_text_clob, 1, 10));
    --
    dbms_output.put_line('dbms_lob.SubStr(my_text_clob, 10, 1): --->' || dbms_lob.SubStr(my_text_clob, 10, 1));
End;
/
--  R e s u l t :
--  SubStr(my_text_varchar, 1, 10)        --->0123456789
--  dbms_lob.SubStr(my_text_clob, 1, 10): --->9
--  dbms_lob.SubStr(my_text_clob, 10, 1): --->0123456789
```